# Django Boolean Field is False when I check it

Tags: python, django, forms

Models.py :

```
class DriverInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    yn = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

Forms.py :

```
class DriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':""}))
    yn = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {{form.name}}
    {{form.yn}}
</form>
```

This is my model and form. When I submit form,
The BooleanField is false when it is checked or nothing when it is not checked.
(I found this problem when I raise a ValueError.)
I want to make it True when it is checked, False when it is not checked.
What should i do?

Comment: You kept default `0` here `yn = forms.BooleanField(required=False)` which needs to be replaces as `False` or `True`. Another point for that you need share code where checkin and etc code is written.

Comment: I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in first of tour view

```
form = DriverForm(request.POST or None)
```

Comment: Sorry but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

In DriverForm change yn field like this

```
yn = forms.BooleanField(initial=False)
```